# Virtual Machines: What components should I upgrade to improve running virtual machines?

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware

at work I need to have one or sometimes two instances of a vmware virtual Windows 7 machine running on my real Windows 7 machine.  The computer I'm using is [Dell Precision 490](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/1809YC1/configuration) from 2009 I believe, possibly earlier.  Running Windows 7 ultimate.

**Problems while running VM's:** The entire computer slows down when a vmware instance is running.  Pages take a while to react to a scroll, applications take forever to launch, and programs hang both in the virtual machines and on the real one.

**So,** what components should I upgrade to improve this?  I guess a more pointed question would be, which components will help the most?

Possible options:

- Getting 8gb of RAM instead of 4gb
- new graphics card
- new processors? (Is that really an option?)

My intuition tells me it will be a combination of the RAM and graphics card.  There is also the possibility that an '09 tower just isn't cut out for vm's and our business should purchase a new tower.

Comment: Thats *not* a horrible choice of hardware as far as virtualisation goes. I suspect you could re-write the question in terms of *finding* your bottleneck "How do I decide what components are slowing down my system" and it might be more useful than asking what to upgrade, sight unseen. Resource manager is probably your best friend here, and I'd probably suggest taking a look at your storage (both in terms of quantity (have a separate drive for VMs), quality (SSDs may be a good investment) and how its laid out). I've run windows 7 VMs on *significantly* less in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphics card is not that important, as you will only use one "machine" on it at a time, normally. The Memory is very important, as is the CPU chip. The i7 series are very quick due to the hyper threading. And, believe it or not, the Hard Drive can be very important as well. it is inherently the slowest point in the system, and now has to share itself with multiple OS's. Look into a good SSHD.